# Replacing one url base with another in php

Tags: php, wordpress, string, permalinks

I'm trying to figure out how to replace one url base with another within php.

So a function that takes "http://www.website1.com/test" and replaces the "http://www.website1.com" to make it "http://www.website2.com/test" .

This is probably a very easy quick function but i'm having trouble finding the right str_replace() to get this done.

```
<?php 
$pre_replace = "http://www.website1.com/test";
$post_replace = str_replace(
  'http://www.website1.com', 
  'http://www.website2.com', 
  $pre_replace); 
echo $post_replace; 
?>
```

isn't quite working for some reason

Answer (score 1):

str_replace should work just fine..

```
<?php
$string = 'http://www.website1.com/test';
$replace = 'http://www.website1.com';
$replaceWith = 'http://www.website2.com';
echo str_replace($replace, $replaceWith, $string);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Now would there be a way to my the string reference the wordpress posts permalink? It's called by <?php the_permalink(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php

   //----------------
   // Original base
   $pre_replace = 'http://www.website1.com/test';

   //----------------
   // New base
   echo $post_replace = str_replace('website1','website2',$pre_replace);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most reliable solution, I'd probably break the URL up using [`parse_url()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), edit the host portion as necessary, and then put it back together.

That way, you can rely on any bugfixes that have made it into [`parse_url()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) over the years rather than reinventing the parser wheel.